# AngularJS: ngAnimate and ng-repeat not working in >1.1.5?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying around with some things. My App works with Angular 1.2.8. I want to animate a list - I also found a workin example for ng-animate working together with ng-repeat. But this one uses Angular 1.1.5. I wasn't able to get it running under another version, regardless of which I tried?!

**html**

```
<div ng-init="items=['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolar', 'Sit', 'Consectetur', 'Adipisicing', 'Elit', 'Sed', 'Do'];">
<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-query" style="width: 80px" />
<ul>
<li ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
<a href="#"> {{item}} </a>
</li> 
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.animate-enter, 
.animate-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
} 

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active, 
.animate-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    height: 30px;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active,
.animate-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -50px;
    height: 0px;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knzo/6svvm05h/2/) (AngularJS 1.1.5)

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knzo/5qhnc90o/) (AngularJS 1.2.8)

The only difference between these fiddles is the angular.js. I tried to add angular-animate.js as well, but with no success.

How can that be? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: be carefull, angular change all the ngAnimate in 1.2... here is a reference of what was changed http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Comment: this page is out of dated, and you have the doc of angular animate 1.1.5 http://www.nganimate.org/

Comment: Thanks alot guys, got it workin with the new syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/knzo/5qhnc90o/2/